# How do I run a looped sound file one time, each time the App runs?

Tags: xcode, audio, avfoundation, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to play a looped sound file one time, each time the app is opened.  I'm doing this because I currently have the code in the viewDidLoad of my initial viewController. The problem was that each time I'd switch views and then go back to the initial view controller, it would play the sound file again and the sounds would overlap and it just sounded awful. I've posted my code below.  Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
{


    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
          boolForKey:@"loadSongOnce"]) {




NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cartoon Sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
theAudio.delegate = self;
theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
[theAudio play];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES
                                            forKey:@"loadSongOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
//self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
// self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
// [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

if(![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"firstTime"] isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Yes" forKey:@"firstTime"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ApplaunchCount"] + 1) forKey:@"ApplaunchCount"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ApplaunchCount"] + 1) forKey:@"ApplaunchCount"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ApplaunchCount"] % 1 ==0)
    {
        //Play sound file here
    }
}
return YES;}
```

This shows that every time the app is killed (closed is multitasking), it will restart the sound. Let me know if this works, and just as before if not let me know!

Comment: I tried this out and it doesn't seem to be working. The music just doesn't play at all when the game starts up. I tried killing the app and opening it again to see if the music would start up then but nothing happened. Any suggestions? And again, thank you for the help haha I'm sorry if this is a pain.

Comment: No you are fine, did you put it in the AppDelegate.m?

Comment: I deleted the app from the simulator and ran it again and it worked perfectly! Thank for for all the help :)

Comment: GREAT! So glad it worked! You are so welcome! Have a great week!

Answer (score 1):

Well what you would need to do is determine weather this is the first time loading the app or not. We would need to store this data as NSUserDefaults, because it is easy and simple.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application … {
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {
  // display alert...
  [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];
}
// rest of initialization ...}
```

Basically this tells the app if this is the first time loading the app, (play sound, you add that) and if not (don't play sound). After the sound is played, the bool will know it should change to YES and it will not run again, until you reload the app. When you go back to the view, that is where the if statement comes into play to tell the app that YES you already played the sound, and to not play it again!
Let me know if this works, and if not I will see what I can do!

Comment: It seemed to work fine :). The only problem is when I upload the app to my device and then double tap the home button and shut the app down, then reopen it, the music has stopped playing. I'm sorry if I'm getting too specific but if you have any advice on how to fix this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: okay have to post my answer as an answer not a comment because too long.

Comment: Oh so you are saying you want the music to continue? If you want it to continue, it should automatically if you close the app and reopen it with in (ex 5 minutes). But when you kill the app (device and then double tap the home button and shut the app down, then reopen it) it will have to restart the music ***Try my answer below***

Comment: Yeah I have a game and I'm trying to get the music file to just constantly play throughout the game. It's just that overlapping problem that I'm trying to solve. But thanks for all your help. I'll try out your other answer

Comment: Okay yeah try my other answer, and let me know what that does for you. If that does not work. Tell me and I will see If I can get something else to work for you :)